How to replace a image url with a local image in const? react js
I want to replace the website image with a local image. How can I do that in a const?
const features = [
{
      name: 'Refined details',
      description:
        'We design every detail with the best materials and finishes. This laptop sleeve features durable canvas with double-stitched construction, a felt interior, and a high quality zipper that hold up to daily use.',
      imageSrc: 'https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/product-feature-07-detail-02.jpg',
      imageAlt: 'Detail of zipper pull with tan leather and silver rivet.',
    },
]

I tried to import the image and use the following code, but it doesn't work.
import Image from "next/image";
import multimodal from '@/assets/multimodal.png';


const features = [
    {
      name: 'High-Quality Multisource & Multimodal Data',
      description:
        'Our laptop sleeve is compact and precisely fits 13" devices. The zipper allows you to access the interior with ease, and the front pouch provides a convenient place for your charger cable.',
      imageSrc: multimodal,
      imageAlt: 'White canvas laptop sleeve with gray felt interior, silver zipper, and tan leather zipper pull.',
    },
]

It is not showing as an error, but the image is not shown on the web page. I also tried the following code. It is also not work.
const features = [
    {
      name: 'High-Quality Multisource & Multimodal Data',
      description:
        'Our laptop sleeve is compact and precisely fits 13" devices. The zipper allows you to access the interior with ease, and the front pouch provides a convenient place for your charger cable.',
      imageSrc: '@/assets/multimodal.png',
      imageAlt: 'White canvas laptop sleeve with gray felt interior, silver zipper, and tan leather zipper pull.',
    },
]


Are you asking how to do features[0].imageSrc = 'https://tailwindui.com/img/ecommerce-images/product-feature-07-detail-02.jpg' ?

Actually，I want to replace the website image with a local image. but I don't how to do it in a const.

Please read how to ask and edit your question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it will be closed.

Have I made it clear now?

"It is not showing an error" - look in the network tab of Chrome. Was image is it trying to load? Are there network errors? Look in the DOM. What is the src attribute of the image? How are you using imageSrc? Please also read https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images#local-images


const creates a constant reference to a value, not the value itself.
This means the variable itself cannot be reassigned to a different object.
However, the object's properties can be added, removed, or updated.



const features = [
    {
      name: 'Minimal and thoughtful',
      description:
        'Our laptop sleeve is compact and precisely fits 13" devices. The zipper allows you to access the interior with ease, and the front pouch provides a convenient place for your charger cable.',
      imageSrc:'@/assets/multisource.png',
      imageAlt: 'White canvas laptop sleeve with gray felt interior, silver zipper, and tan leather zipper pull.'
  
    },
]
//Its an array of objects hence the loop, otherwise just the line to modify is enough.
for (const feature of features) {
    if( feature.name === 'Minimal and thoughtful') //your condition
        //line to modify
        feature.imageSrc =  'your new image'
}

console.log(features)



